# Can I use any audio interface with the Pro Tools 9 that comes with an Mbox Mini?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, digital-audio, pro-tools

All I know is it is the version of Pro Tools that comes with the ["Pro Tools 9 + Mbox Mini" package](http://www.avid.com/US/products/Pro-Tools-plus-Mbox-Mini) (see also [here](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/avid-pro-tools-9-mbox-mini?src=3WFRWXX)).

Kinda sounds like you can use any interface with it (or no interface, which I assume means soundcard), but some confirmation from someone with direct experience would be awesome!

Comment: creating tags required 300 reputation, so that we don't have misspelled tags that link to spam websites

Comment: By `any`, do you mean any of the interfaces on the mbox? or any connected to the computer?  FWIW, I have used previous versions of ProTools without dedicated hardware... just the computer's built-in interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro Tools 9 is the first version that allows *any* interface to be used with the software. See also, under requirements:

> Interface: Works with ASIO, Core Audio, WDM, MME, and multi-client drivers.

So, if your interface uses ASIO or Core Audio – and most of them do – you should be fine. See also: [Pro Tools Hardware Checker](http://www.pro-tools-expert.com/pro-tools-hardware-checker/)

Comment: great to know -- since I am now a proud owner of PT9 ;)  tyvm and thanks to all who responded!